# How to bind in Java using DN and Password in LDAP?

Tags: java, ldap, bind

I want to search a user from LDAP and after getting the user I want to connect (validate)
that particular user using his DN and Password
I have successfully getting the DN but dont know how to bind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LDAP bind() operation corresponds to the following in JNDI:

1. Constructing an `InitialDirContext` or `InitialLdapContext` with enough information in the environment to cause a login, i.e. a security principal and credentials, or
2. Calling `reconnect()` on an `LdapContext` initially obtained without any security information in the environment, or with security information relating to a different principal, but whose environment has subsequently been modified.

Comment: Thanks for tip, the second one was very helpful for me: If you already have LdapContext and you want to verify same user against it, you can copy you DirContext using `lookup("")`, change principal+credential using `addToEnvironment(...)` and just try `reconnect(null)` :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example that I took from the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html) :

```
// Set up the environment for creating the initial context
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
    "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:389/o=JNDITutorial");

// Authenticate as S. User and password "mysecret"
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=S. User, ou=NewHires, o=JNDITutorial");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "mysecret");
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

You have to choose your right authentication model. I have tried it before and worked fine.

Comment: Ya this works even for me.
Problem is that after getting DirContext ctx object i want to bind a new User to check its validity
I am having the full DN for the user and password
is it possible ?

Comment: This is from the Oracle JNDI Tutorial, not the 'official documentation', which would be the Javadoc or the JNDI Specification.

Answer (score 1):

When a connection is made to a directory server using LDAP, the connection state is unauthenticated. Requests can be transmitted on an unauthenticated connection, assuming the server administrators permit unauthenticated requests. The [BIND](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.2) request is used to change authentication state of a connection.

Here is an example of searching and authenticating using the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/): [SimpleBindExample.java](http://code.google.com/p/ldap-sample-code/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/samplecode/bind/SimpleBindExample.java). This example searches for an entry given a base object, naming attribute, and username, and then attempts to authenticate using a `simple bind`. Examples using a SASL bind could be constructed just as easily.

Comment: Link to SimpleBindExample.java seems to be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have **LdapContext** opened using your credentials, you can copy it, change principal+credential in its environment and try reconnect:

```
LdapContext userContext = ldapContext.newInstance(null); // copy context
userContext.addToEnvironment(InitialDirContext.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userDn);
userContext.addToEnvironment(InitialDirContext.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
userContext.reconnect(null); // throws NamingException if creds wrong
userContext.close();
```

If it throws NamingException, credentials are wrong. It it is successful, credentials are ok. ;)

(This is useful if you have only LdapContext, but not the InitialDirContext, available.)

Comment: If you create the context with one principal, and also specify to use connection pooling, will your logic result in a new connection being created?  Or, will it reuse an existing connection from the pool?

Comment: When I try this doesn't work. I change the user and password. But if we set the original credentials back it reconnects.

Comment: I think one should be aware that Java 8 and before will *not* set up a new connection, but 9-13 seem to set up a fully new connection with [this change](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11u/commit/7b7d6755b5eb173c7f567997b869615cbbc8c7e5). JDK 14 [reverts](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/6717d7e59db4) that again.